# Using awk to sum the values of a column, based on the values of another column

Tags: shell, unix, awk

I am trying to sum up certain numbers in a column using `awk`. I would like to sum up numbers in second column with each other who has same IP adress.

```
2001:778:0:1::21 44
2001:778:0:1::21 1406
2001:778:0:1::21 66643
88.222.10.7 66643
88.222.10.7 1406
88.222.10.7 -
88.222.10.7 66643
88.222.10.7 1406
121.141.172.40 235
121.141.172.40 235
```

Desired output:

```
2001:778:0:1::21 68093
88.222.10.7 136098
121.141.172.40 470
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, special thanks for adding sample input and output into CODE TAGS, on SO we encourage users to add their efforts also along with their question's samples so kindly do add your efforts which you have put in order to fix your problem in your post, cheers and happy learning on this great site SO.

Comment: For a non awk way, look up datamash.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***1st solution:*** Could you please try following.(in case you don't bother about sequence of 1st field in output)

```
awk '{a[$1]+=$NF} END{for(i in a){print i,a[i]}}'  Input_file
```

***2nd solution:*** In case you want to keep order of 1st field same as Input_file's sequence then try following.

```
awk '!b[$1]++{c[++count]=$1} {a[$1]+=$NF} END{for(i=1;i<=count;i++){print c[i],a[c[i]]}}'  Input_file
```

Comment: It works, thanks! And one more question.. What is the best way to complete this task without using awk?

Comment: @EdgarasAlšauskas, IMHO we could do this in shell too but I think doing it in awk or any other language will be more efficient honestly.

Comment: Thank You very much for answering!

Comment: wow , wow, wow. worked in one shot!